# strange behaviour for xpath "//tr" and etree.findall while scraping in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, xpath, elementtree

I am scraping a website(with permission). But here i am getting a very irregular behaviour while selecting all the `tr` elements of a `table`.
If a select using xpath it gives me 67 length while if i select using findall it gives me 3 which is true.
Working example

```
import urllib2
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
import string
import csv

req_headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safar/537.36'
    }
anz_extra_url = u"https://sg.anz.com/apps/wealth/"
request = urllib2.Request(anz_extra_url, None, req_headers)
page = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
table_root = etree.fromstring(page, parser)
all_tables = table_root.xpath("//table[@width=869]")
len(all_tables[1].findall("tr"))
#output = 3
len(all_tables[1].xpath("//tr"))
#output = 67
```

Edit:
Structure of all_tables[1] is given below

```
etree.tostring(all_tables[1])
#output
<table width="869" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">&#13;\n                            <tr>&#13;\n                                <td width="35%" align="left" bgcolor="#004165" style="font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px 15px;">&#13;\n                                    Placement Amount</td>&#13;\n                                <td width="65%" bgcolor="#004165" style="font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px 15px;;" align="center">&#13;\n                                    9-Month ANZ Instant Interest Time Deposit Interest Rate                                </td>&#13;\n                            </tr>&#13;\n                            <tr>&#13;\n                                <td align="left" style="padding: 5px 15px;">&#13;\n                                    SGD150,000 and above&#13;\n                                </td>&#13;\n                                <td align="center" style="padding: 5px 15px;">&#13;\n                                    1.38% p.a.&#13;\n                                </td>&#13;\n                            </tr>&#13;\n                            <tr>&#13;\n                                <td align="left" bgcolor="#C6DFEA" style="padding: 5px 15px;">&#13;\n                                    Below SGD150,000</td>&#13;\n                                <td align="center" bgcolor="#C6DFEA" style="padding: 5px 15px;">&#13;\n                                    0.70% p.a.&#13;\n                                </td>&#13;\n                            </tr>&#13;\n                        </table>&#13;\n                        \n
```

So why is it behaving like this ?

Thanks

Comment: What does `all_tables[1]` look like? What are the child elements of `tr`? `//tr` will return all `tr` elements and their decendents.

Comment: @DaveCoast added structure of table

Answer (score 1):

The xpath expression `//tr` matches all `tr` elements, starting from the document root. If you want `tr` elements which are descendants of the context, you need `.//tr`

Comment: isn't that implicit since i am operating xpath on given table only. Thing is some time //tr works and sometimes doesn't . Can you give some more details about the behaviour ?

Comment: No, it's not implicit. It's like filepaths: if it starts with a `/`, its an absolute path which starts at the document root and the only thing the current context is used for is to find the appropriate root. If you want to start from the provided context, you must start with `.`